Adjusting padding of input and select
I'm trying to make a registration form.
The first 4 inputs (text, email, number and select) are inside a div. The select bar doesn't take the same padding space as the other inputs above it and its a little bit to the left, also, it doesn't respect the min-height: 2em that I assigned as the ones above it.
Also, the texts of the labels aren't in the same place as those below, they are a little bit ot the right.
The text area appears to have the same issue as the select bar.
I tried giving the form a padding of 40px and the input, textarea and select a width of 100%.


body{
    background-color: #041f43;
    color: #041f43;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

h1, p{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;   
}

form{
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 40px;  
}

.group{
    margin: 0 auto 1.25rem auto;
}


#name-label, #email-label, #number-label, #selection-label{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
}


input, textarea, select{
  margin: 12px 0 12px ;
  min-height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

label{
    display: block;
}

legend{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.inline {
    width: unset;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
  }


input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    height: 2em;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    background-color: #9494dd;
    border-color: white;
    color: white;
    min-width: 300px;
  }
    <h1 id="title">Welcome!</h1>
    <p id="description">We're here to help you with your tasks!</p>

    <form id="survey-form">

        <div class="group">

            <label id="name-label">Name:
                <input id="name" class="group1" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
            </label>

            <label id="email-label">E-mail:
                <input id="email" class="group1" type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" required/>
            </label>

            <label id="number-label">Age (optional):
                <input id="number" class="group1" type="number" min="13" max="100" placeholder="Enter your age"/>
            </label>

            <label id="selection-label">Select your age:
                <select id="dropdown" class="group1">
                    <option value="selectOne">Select one</option>
                    <option value="socialMedia">Social media</option>
                    <option value="podcast">freeCodeCamp Podcast</option>
                    <option value="friend">Friend</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </label>

        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <legend id="recommendation">Would you recommend us to a friend?</legend>
            <label for="radio1">Of course!
                <input id="radio1" class="inline" type="radio" name="purpose" value="yes" checked/></label>
            <label for="radio2">I don't think so
                <input id="radio2" class="inline" type="radio" name="purpose" value="no"/>
            </label>
            <label for="radio3">Maybe
                <input id="radio3" class="inline" type="radio" name="purpose" value="maybe"/>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <legend>Would you like to receive more information?</legend>
            <label for="radio4">Newsletter
                <input id="radio4" class="inline" type="checkbox" name="" value="newsletter" checked/>
            </label>
            <label for="radio5">Discounts
                <input id="radio5" class="inline" type="checkbox" name="purpose" value="discounts"/>
            </label>
            <label for="radio6">Team Challenges
                <input id="radio6" class="inline" type="checkbox" name="purpose" value="teamChallenges"/>
            </label>
            <label for="radio7">Daily Challenges
                <input id="radio7" class="inline" type="checkbox" name="purpose" value="dailyChallenges"/>
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="group">
            <label class="group1">
                <legend>Do you have any comments or questions?</legend>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="45" class="fieldset1"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <input id="submit" type="submit"/>

    </form>




By default, <select> elements use system UI widgets, which ignore most style rules. However, you can turn off the system UI connection by applying the style appearance: none. The <select> will then behave much more like an <input> from a styling perspective.
I’d also suggest that rather than specifying a height or max-height for your inputs and selects, specify a consistent padding instead, along with box-sizing: border-box. That should fix your alignment issues.
And here’s a little bonus for you. The first option in your select is really a placeholder, so it would be nice if the text of this option could be gray in color, to match the placeholders in the inputs. Try using :has to this style the color of the select conditionally, like this:
select:has(> option:first-child:checked) {
  color: darkgray;
}

A snippet to demonstrate all my suggestions:


body {
  background-color: #041f43;
  color: #041f43;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

h1, p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;   
}

form {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 40px;  
}

.group {
  margin: 0 auto 1.25rem auto;
}


#name-label, #email-label, #number-label, #selection-label{
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}

input, textarea, select {
  margin: 12px 0 12px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

legend {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inline {
  width: unset;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: #9494dd;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  min-width: 300px;
}
  
select {
  appearance: none;
}

select:has(> option:first-child:checked) {
  color: darkgray;
}
<h1 id="title">Welcome!</h1>
    <p id="description">We're here to help you with your tasks!</p>

    <form id="survey-form">

        <div class="group">

            <label id="name-label">Name:
                <input id="name" class="group1" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
            </label>

            <label id="email-label">E-mail:
                <input id="email" class="group1" type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" required/>
            </label>

            <label id="number-label">Age (optional):
                <input id="number" class="group1" type="number" min="13" max="100" placeholder="Enter your age"/>
            </label>

            <label id="selection-label">Select your age:
                <select id="dropdown" class="group1">
                    <option value="selectOne">Select one</option>
                    <option value="socialMedia">Social media</option>
                    <option value="podcast">freeCodeCamp Podcast</option>
                    <option value="friend">Friend</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </label>

        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <legend id="recommendation">Would you recommend us to a friend?</legend>
            <label for="radio1">Of course!
                <input id="radio1" class="inline" type="radio" name="purpose" value="yes" checked/></label>
            <label for="radio2">I don't think so
                <input id="radio2" class="inline" type="radio" name="purpose" value="no"/>
            </label>
            <label for="radio3">Maybe
                <input id="radio3" class="inline" type="radio" name="purpose" value="maybe"/>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <legend>Would you like to receive more information?</legend>
            <label for="radio4">Newsletter
                <input id="radio4" class="inline" type="checkbox" name="" value="newsletter" checked/>
            </label>
            <label for="radio5">Discounts
                <input id="radio5" class="inline" type="checkbox" name="purpose" value="discounts"/>
            </label>
            <label for="radio6">Team Challenges
                <input id="radio6" class="inline" type="checkbox" name="purpose" value="teamChallenges"/>
            </label>
            <label for="radio7">Daily Challenges
                <input id="radio7" class="inline" type="checkbox" name="purpose" value="dailyChallenges"/>
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="group">
            <label class="group1">
                <legend>Do you have any comments or questions?</legend>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="45" class="fieldset1"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <input id="submit" type="submit"/>

    </form>



